# Правильно написать как?

Tags: пунктуация

Оба варианта возможны?

> 1. У нас много чего интересного происходит — например, вчера, в 18-м часу, я случайно, неправильно прочитав предложение, моего друга чуть-чуть предал.

> 2. У нас много чего интересного происходит; например, вчера, в 18-м часу, я случайно, неправильно прочитав предложение, моего друга чуть-чуть предал.

> 3. У нас много чего интересного происходит, например вчера, в 18-м часу, я случайно, неправильно прочитав предложение, моего друга чуть-чуть предал.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

(1) *У нас много чего интересного происходит;   например, вчера, в 18-м часу, я случайно, неправильно прочитав предложение, моего друга чуть-чуть предал.*

**Точка с запятой**. Относительная самостоятельность сообщений.

(2) *У нас много чего интересного **происходит. Например**, вчера, в 18-м часу, я случайно, неправильно прочитав предложение, моего друга чуть-чуть предал.*

Точка, два **отдельных** сообщения.

Comment: Почему нельзя тире и двоеточие?

Comment: Я это так вижу... Ослабленная семантическая связь,  структура относительно законченного предложения.  При постановке тире или двоеточия связь прослеживается однозначно.

Answer (score 1):

*У нас много чего интересного происходит — например, вчера, в 18-м часу, я случайно, неправильно прочитав предложение, моего друга чуть-чуть предал.* — обычное обособление вводного слова *например*.

*У нас много чего интересного происходит: например, вчера, в 18-м часу, я случайно, неправильно прочитав предложение, моего друга чуть-чуть предал.* — автор подчëркивает значимость части после двоеточия; *много интересного* — обобщающее слово.

*У нас много чего интересного происходит, например вчера, в 18-м часу, я случайно, неправильно прочитав предложение, моего друга чуть-чуть предал* — *например* входит в уточняющий оборот и не отделяется от него запятой.

Многовариантная пунктуация; каждый вариант может быть верен, но разный смысл знаков.